# How do I highlight a selection made programmatically in a Winforms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, selection

I've not gone into much research here, but the intuitive thing is not working:

```
private void SerachButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String serchTerm = searchTerm1.Text;
   String text = usualTextBox.Text;


   Int32 index = text.IndexOf(serchTerm);

   if (index >= 0)
   {
      usualTextBox.Select(index, serchTerm.Length);
   }
}
```

`SelectedText`, `SelectionLength` and `SelectionStart` properties are as I expect them after `Select` is called but there's no visible selection.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I've also tried `RichTextBox`. When I set background and text colors for the selection it shows up, but it won't unselect automatically when you manually select another part of text or just click on a position in text. Are these two types of selection inherently different and if you select programmatically you have to also deselect programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `usualTextBox.HideSelection` to `false` so that the selection remains visible when the focus is not in the `TextBox`.

Comment: Umm, I don't see this property in a WPF TextBox

Comment: I'm not surprised, WPF does things differently to WinForms.